# Concerned after many squats and suddenly felt sick / super-sleepy / light-headed for 1 whole hour?

Tags: squats, illness

Heavy sickness and tiredness and distant/faint feeling lasted one whole hour - feeling a little faint is normal for squats on a heavy weight *obviously*, but slightly concerned about length of time this lasted - it felt serious for about 30 mins

Seems really strange. At first wondered if it might be heart attack but no pain in chest

10sets x 10 reps x 90kg rest:60s

But it hit me half way through 3rd set of bench-presses straight after which are normally never any trouble

Starting to feel ok now, but confused as to what just happened and if this is normal. Has anyone else experienced it? I've not experienced anything so severe before and I've done weights in much lower set-numbers 3x8, 3x10 for a long while and go running 1-2 times a week for an hour. Wasn't expecting this. Not sure if I should be concerned or what, literally felt like curling up and going to sleep and like I was close to being sick a lot. Anyone experienced this? Probably not a heart attack since now I feel way better. Just puzzled as to how this feels

Also can find lots of posts of people saying they felt sick - fine, but none for the length of time involved here.

I'm starting to feel a lot better now since starting to write this.

Added: 1RM squats is probably ~120kg
       I just went back and completed workout this morning and was fine - have to assume since I'm stil typing was not heart attack. But weirdest thing. Wonder if could have been lactic acid overload or something weird making me sick

Comment: Same here, sometimes i feel that my spirit wants to quit my body. My legs day is really heavy, no big rest (1 min)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the rest of your workout looked like, and how close you were to your 1RM max, and those matter. 90 kilos doesn't mean much, since that might be 80% or 40% of your max, which is much more relevant.

Either way, 10 sets of 10 reps is a lot of volume. That's 100 weighted squats, whereby most programs that are volume heavy will come in around maybe 1/3 - 1/2 of that.

There are a lot of variables at play but some things I would consider or monitor:

- Did you [bonk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitting_the_wall)? It's entirely possible that you consumed all of your blood sugar and the feeling of nausea and wooziness is normal in that area.
- Do you remember your heart rate? Record your heart rate when you're fine and working out, then take it again if you feel similar symptoms.
- If it is a diet thing, consider sipping on some "intra-workout" stuff, which can be as simple as gatorade (or similar), maybe cut down with some water.
- Read up on [electrolyte imbalances](http://cancer.unm.edu/cancer/cancer-info/cancer-treatment/side-effects-of-cancer-treatment/less-common-side-effects/blood-test-abnormalities/electrolyte-imbalance/). This can be addressed (in the short term) with some of the "intra-workout" products. Personally I've had this, and heat cramps, when working out in hot humid areas.

And not as a cop-out answer but being honest: you should run this past your doctor. If you ever have a concern of:

> At first wondered if it might be heart attack

, it's worth the doctor's visit to at least establish a baseline. Odds are it's nothing serious, but I had a (very fit) friend with a similar feeling one day and it ended up being a heart rhythm issue. He required an electrical shock to reset his heart and follow up monitoring, definitely not the the kind of thing you want to tough out.

Comment: Have a runner friend and asked him about the bonk and he said it comes from e.g. running 20 miles - i.e. very long time and said he just felt tired. Not quite the sickness / crushing sick / faint feeling.

I may mention to a doctor, but don't expect anything helpful from them.

I'd estimate 1RM at around 130 but is something of a guess.